# How can I extrapolate to higher values in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, extrapolation

I have the following data:

```
T=[0,100,300]
```

and

```
a=[2.8796,2.8785,2.886]
```

and I want to extrapolate and know what `a` will I get at `T=600` in Matlab. 
How can I do that?

Comment: There is not one way to answer this question. Is there some underlying relationship between `T` and `a`? Do you need to [interpolate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/interpolation-1.html) your data? Do you want a linear interpolation, polynomial interpolation, spline interpolation, some other interpolation?

Comment: Is there an underlying equation describing the relationship between a and T? What type of interpolation are you looking for?

Comment: I know that there are different ways of doing it. I do not have any equation for that and I do not know if it's linear or polynomial, so I have to try and check the value at T=600 and then decide which one gives me the best answer for what I want.  :(

Comment: These are experimental values for temperature and thermal expansion which depending on the material can have different relations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If its linear the code below solves this

```
clear all
close all

T=[0,100,300];
a=[2.8796,2.8785,2.886];
reg = polyfit(T,a,1);

figure
hold on
plot(T,a,'bx')
plot(T,reg(2)+T.*reg(1),'k-')
plot(600,reg(2)+600*reg(1),'ro')
plot(600,interp1(T,a,600,'linear','extrap'),'md')
legend('observations','lin. regression','pred. at 600p polyfit','pred. at 600p interp1')

val_polyfit = reg(2)+600*reg(1)
val_interp1 = interp1(T,a,600,'linear','extrap')
diff = val_polyfit/val_interp1
```

yields

```
val_polyfit =

    2.8924


val_interp1 =

    2.8972


diff =

    0.9983
```

Comment: Interesting, it does yield a different result compared to interp1. Probably because of the small number of observation samples

Comment: @GameOfThrows: thats indeed funny. I had that in the past when using excel and R, and I always considered R more trustworthy... Did not to expect that it would differ within one program.

Comment: @GameOfThrows Don't have matlab to execute right now, how much is the difference between this method and `interp1`?

Comment: I guess polyfit fits a single linear, i.e. a least-squares approximation, not an interpolant. `interp1` gives a piecewise linear interpolation.

Comment: @RaGe I think it is as Andras Deak says, the error is small 0.005.

Comment: @RaGe & @ GameOfThrows: I added the results above. Its 0.17%.

Comment: Since we don't know how the data can be shaped, it's probably more meaningful to use the piecewise linear interpolant for extrapolation (imagine the error in case where the 3 data points are on a parabola). Of course if the basis data points are already fairly linear, then it doesn't make much of a difference (and if it's *supposed to be* linear, then the `polyfit` is more meaningful, i.e. more robust).

Comment: the code seems what I want to do but 17% error is quite large. Maybe I should try interp1 instead of polyfit! The value looks more reasonable for my purpose!!! :/

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Elin not 17% but 0.17% ...

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thanks @horseshoe :)

Answer (score 2):

For Linear Interpolation:
`aextra = interp1(T,a,600,'linear','extrap')`

Comment: Why are you using the interpolation function for extrapolation?

Comment: @SharanDuggirala there is no mathematical difference between inter and extra polation, just a name depending on where in the range your doing the fit